# Is there a way of finding out the remaining two numbers of pythagorean triple if one of the side is given

Tags: geometry, elementary-number-theory, pythagorean-triples

I am solving one question related to right triangle and I have to find out the remaining two numbers of the pythagorean triple if one of the number is given. I know there can be many triples possible , but I just need to find one triple.
Thank you for your help :)

Comment: If you look up the reference in my answer below, you will see how to find all Pythagorean triplets that  have the side you are given or you will be able to prove that no such triplet exists.

Answer (score 2):

If the number is odd, its square can be represented as $2k+1$.  Then one triple is $k, \sqrt{2k+1}, k+1$.  If the number is even, it is $2k$ and you can use $k^2-1, 2k, k^2+1$

Comment: To ask, what if the number is 3 that is known and 4 and 5 aren't known (for the sake of argument). If you represent that as 2k+1, k=1. No matter which way I slice that, I come up with something that's not a triple. Can you explain what I'm seeing wrong with your response?

Comment: @Johnq  If the number is $3$, then $2k + 1 = 3^2 = 9$, so $k = 4$.  The desired triple is then $k = 4$, $\sqrt{2k + 1} = \sqrt{9} = 3$, and $k + 1 = 5$.  I suspect you overlooked the fact that Ross Millikan stated that the *square* can be represented as $2k + 1$.

Comment: I did indeed. Oops.

Comment: The part about even numbers is wrong. Should be k*k-1,2k,k*k+1

Answer (score 2):

If your number $x$ is even, then any factorization $x/2=m\cdot n$, with $m>n$, gives a triple $(m^2+n^2, m^2-n^2,x)$.

It $x$ is odd, then again factor it as $x=m\cdot n$, with $m>n$, and a triple is 
$\left({m^2+n^2\over2},{m^2-n^2\over2},x\right)$.

If $x$ is not prime and $d$ is one of its divisors, then you can find other triples by considering the triples generated by $x/d$ and multiplying them by $d$

This works, however, as long as $x$ represents the length of a cathetus.